# Compact linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Today in lecture we were told that for a linear compact operator $T$ on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with infinite-dimensional range, we have that

$\ker(T)^{\perp}$ is infinite-dimensional, too. Does anybody know why this is the case?

I know that this is the same as the closure of the range of the adjoint operator, and in fact the adjoint operator is compact, too. But I don't know if this already tells us that this space is in fact infinite-dimensional?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *I don't know if this already tells us that this space is in fact infinite dimensional*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the argument $ran(T)$ is infinite dimensional then $ran(T^*)$ is it too, seems to be unclear to me.

Comment: Alternatively, you can check that $T$ takes a linearly independent set for $\ker (T)^\perp$ to a linearly independent set in $\range (T)$

Comment: Hmm, this is harder than I expected.  I'll delete my answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

1. A linear operator $A$ in a Hilbert space $H$ is of finite rank if and only if $A^*$ is too. This is easy: As vector spaces we have $H/\ker(A)=R(A)$, and so $\dim(\ker(A)^\perp) \leq \dim(R(A)) <\infty$, but $\ker(A)^\perp = \overline{R(A^*)}$ so that $A^*$ has finite rank whenever $A$ does. The converse is obvious.
2. Now if $\ker(A)^\perp$ is finite dimensional we get, by the same identity as above, that $R(A^*)$ is finite dimensional and so $A$ has finite rank, a contradiction.